# Laravel array validation if atleast one fails return single message

Tags: arrays, forms, validation, laravel

I have form where I can add up to 30 option fields (option[1], option[2], ...) and for now Im using **'option.*' => 'required'** rule in request validation but with this there is a little problem, if you submit form with all option fields empty it shows long error message with each option field required, but I need that it shows only one message for all options like: **"Each option field is required"**.

Any ideas how to make it?
Thanks!

Comment: set custom message for this field?

Comment: you mean each select field is required? Do you only have one select with 30 options or 30 select fields?

Comment: They are not selects, but text inputs (can add up to 30) and all of them are  required but I need to return only one message not 30x same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this. I will post it here in case somebody needs it:

Basically, you need to override `formatErrors` method in your request validation class

```
protected function formatErrors(Validator $validator)
{
    $errors = parent::formatErrors($validator);

    // this will remove the keys that have index larger than 0
    $keys = array_filter(array_keys($errors), function($item) {
        $parts = explode('.', $item);

        // you might want to modify this to match your fields, 
        // I had another level of keys
        if (count($parts) === 3 and is_numeric($parts[1]) and (int)$parts[1] > 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });

    $errors = array_intersect_key($errors, array_flip($keys));

    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how to use the above method in  request validation class?